# Use your local development environment to edit this Function App

Tags: azure, azure-functions

For reasons beyond my control we dont yet have a release pipeline for Azure Functions

However, I would like to be able to enable/disable functions on an environment via the portal

This does not seem to be possible

Is there a way around this?

How can I release a version that doesnt have this restriction?

The function app itself was created in the portal then I deployed into it

Comment: We can either programmatically or through settings disable or enable functions. Please refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/disable-function?tabs=portal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use your local development environment to edit this Function App**

Here are the steps to Enable/Disable the Function App through Portal

Steps:

1. Login to portal Azure Portal
2. Under the Subscription and the resource group go to the Function app created
3. Click on the App overview where you can able to see the Enable or Disable options.

[image: Disable Azure Function]